# How to wait for a flow to complete emitting the values

Tags: kotlin

I have a function "getUser" in my Repository which emits an object representing a user based on the provided id.

[flow function](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hYFS6.png)

```
fun getUser(id: String) = callbackFlow {
    val collectionReference: CollectionReference =
        FirebaseFirestore.getInstance().collection(COLLECTION_USERS)

    val query: Query = collectionReference.whereEqualTo(ID, id)

    query.get().addOnSuccessListener {
        val lst = it.toObjects(User::class.java)
        if (lst.isEmpty())
            offer(null)
        else
            offer(it.toObjects(User::class.java)[0])
    }

    awaitClose()
}
```

I need these values in another class. I loop over a list of ids and I add the collected user to a new list. How can I wait for the list to be completed when I collect the values, before calling return?

[collector function](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hGqwX.png)

```
private fun computeAttendeesList(reminder: Reminder): ArrayList<User> {
    val attendeesList = arrayListOf<User>()
    for (friend in reminder.usersToShare) {
        repoScope.launch {
            Repository.getUser(friend).collect {
                it?.let { user ->
                    if (!attendeesList.contains(user))
                        attendeesList.add(user)
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return attendeesList
}
```

I do not want to use live data since this is not a UI-related class.

Comment: Please do not post screenshots, they are not searchable and it's hard to build a useful response because we need to type everything. Please paste the code using a code block within your question.

Comment: What do you want your `computeAttendeesList` to do while waiting? Do you want it to suspend? or block the current thread? If the former, you should make your method `suspend` itself, if the latter you can make use of `runBlocking`. In either case, you have multiple ways to do this, so it would help having more info about which scope you want to run things in, and which threads you want to block (if any).

Comment: Sorry @Joffrey, I posted the code. Well, I need to be a blocking code, only after the `attendeesList` is computed, I want to be returned in order to be used by another function.

Comment: Also, is your `repoScope` single-threaded? Because you are concurrently updating an ArrayList that is not thread safe here.

Comment: If you want it to offer a finished list, then have a `suspend fun getList() : List<T>` and call that from a suspending context. I think you're trying to solve two problems with one solution. The flow is nice to emit the values that are needed to construct the list, but if you need a finished list, the interested object should simply receive such thing.

Comment: I agree with @MartinMarconcini here. I didn't pay much attention to the `getUser` function, but the overall design seems strange here. `getUser` is used to get a single user, so it should not return a `Flow` but instead be a `suspend` function and return a `User` directly. If what you want is a full list, there is probably a way to query firebase for a list of ids instead (`whereIn()`).

Comment: @Joffrey, the repoScope is this way `val repoScope = CoroutineScope(Job() + Dispatchers.IO)`. If I put the collector function in runBlocking scope, it will be blocked indefinitely since the flow can emit values continously.

Comment: @OprVld So your `repoScope` is multithreaded, be careful with your concurrent updates, they won't work! Regarding the use of `runBlocking`, I don't believe this is how your firebase `Query` is expected to work in the first place. You never close the callbackFlow's channel, but you also never perform the query again, so unless firebase fires your `addOnSuccessListener` callback multiple times, the flow will actually never emit new values, but it will indeed hang.

Comment: If you're not familiar with how to adapt callback based libraries to coroutines API, I suggest you take a look at [this post](https://betterprogramming.pub/how-to-use-kotlin-coroutines-with-firebase-6f8577a3e00f). It basically shows how to use the [kotlinx-coroutines-play-services library](https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.coroutines/tree/master/integration/kotlinx-coroutines-play-services)'s `await` extension for this purpose.

Comment: @Joffrey, thank you. I have changed the function from the repository to a suspending one and I called await() on the queries. Now it works, thank you very much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are multiple problems to address in this code:

1. `getUser()` is meant to return a single `User`, but it currently returns a `Flow<User>`
   which will never end, and never return more than one user.
2. the way the list of users is constructed from multiple concurrent query is not thread safe (because multiple `launch`es are executed on the multi-threaded IO dispatcher, and they all update the same unsafe list directly)
3. the actual use case is to get a list of users from Firebase, but many queries for a single ID are used instead of a single query

### Solution to #1

Let's tackle #1 first. Here is a version of `getUser()` that suspends for a single `User` instead of returning a `Flow`:

```kotlin
suspend fun getUser(id: String): User {
    val collectionReference = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance().collection(COLLECTION_USERS)
    val query = collectionReference.whereEqualTo(ID, id)

    return query.get().await().let { it.toObjects(User::class.java) }.firstOrNull()
}

// use the kotlinx-coroutines-play-services library instead
private suspend fun <T> Task<T>.await(): T {
    return suspendCancellableCoroutine { cont ->
        addOnCompleteListener {
            val e = exception
            if (e == null) {
                @Suppress("UNCHECKED_CAST")
                if (isCanceled) cont.cancel() else cont.resume(result as T)
            } else {
                cont.resumeWithException(e)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

It turns out that this `await()` function was already written (in a better way) and it's available in the [kotlinx-coroutines-play-services library](https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.coroutines/tree/master/integration/kotlinx-coroutines-play-services), so you don't need to actually write it yourself.

### Solution to #2

If we could not rewrite the whole thing according to #3, we could deal with problem #2 this way:

```kotlin
private suspend fun computeAttendeesList(reminder: Reminder): List<User> {
    return reminder.usersToShare
        .map { friendId -> 
            repoScope.async { Repository.getUser(friendId) }
        }
        .map { it.await() }
        .toList()
}
```

### Solution to #3

Instead, we could directly query Firebase for the whole list:

```kotlin
suspend fun getUsers(ids: List<String>): List<User> {
    val collectionReference = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance().collection(COLLECTION_USERS)
    val query = collectionReference.whereIn(ID, ids)

    return query.get().await().let { it.toObjects(User::class.java) }
}
```

And then consume it in a very basic way:

```kotlin
private suspend fun computeAttendeesList(reminder: Reminder): List<User> {
    return Repository.getUsers(reminder.usersToShare)
}
```

Alternatively, you could make this function blocking (remove `suspend`) and wrap your call in `runBlocking` (if you really need to block the current thread).

Note that this solution didn't enforce any dispatcher, so if you want a particular scope or dispatcher, you can wrap one of the suspend function calls with `withContext`.

Comment: Yes, thank you, #3 is the best approach, I have just changed it and it works. Have a nice day!